# Laptop never suspends after closing the lid; `journalctl` is surprisingly empty about it

Tags: drivers, arch-linux, nvidia-graphics-card, suspend

Here is the begining of the "go-to-sleep-because-lid-closed" procedure:

```
Aug 01 21:43:29 wonderland systemd-logind[655]: Suspending...
Aug 01 21:43:29 wonderland kernel: NVRM nvAssertFailedNoLog: Assertion failed: 0 @ osapi.c:1800
Aug 01 21:43:29 wonderland systemd-logind[655]: Lid closed.
```

Note that `kernel` complaints about some failed assertion from the NVidia driver's side...

After that evertyhing goes smoothly as expected, system does fall into a sleep. Once I open the lid back nothing happens, the system is stuck.

Here is how it looks:

```
Aug 01 21:43:30 wonderland kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
Aug 01 21:43:30 wonderland systemd-sleep[7294]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
Aug 01 21:43:30 wonderland systemd[1]: Starting System Suspend...
Aug 01 21:43:30 wonderland systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
```

...and that's it: **no more warning or errors, literally nothing**. I am absolutely sure it is an NVidia driver thing. The drivers are:

```
nvidia-open 535.86.05-3
nvidia-settings 535.86.05-1
nvidia-utils 535.86.05-2
```

The funniest fact about the bug is that it is not determenistiic. Sometimes lid would open just fine; sometimes not. It occurs on about 50% of all occasions.

The `systemd-analyze cat-config systemd/logind.conf` renders only the `HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend` being uncommented; none other setting present.

Also might be useful to know:

```
lspci -k |lspci -k | grep -A 2 -E "(VGA|3D)"
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU116M [GeForce GTX 1660 Ti Mobile] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Lenovo TU116M [GeForce GTX 1660 Ti Mobile]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

---

Now the question. I am desperately stuck on the issue. No log, no warning, no errors, just a cryptic violated assertion. How do I debug it? What'd be the next resonable step to take?

Comment: In a Windows machine, and aside from suspend settings, failure to suspend is always a driver issue. Can you update all drivers in Arch?  Key:  Power Driver, BIOS and in your case perhaps NVidia

Comment: When this happens, what do you have in `ps -e -o pid,ppid,stat,wchan:22,command | awk 'NR == 1 || $3 ~ /^[DZ]/'`?

Comment: @u1686_grawity, how do you want me to submit that command to the shell if my laptop is stuck somewhere at the being of the init sequence? Far distant from where I got my shell up'n'running even without `graphical.traget`?